# Python unicode string and bytes

Tags: python, string, unicode, cryptography

I'm using Crypto framework ...

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA    
new_key=RSA.generate(1024,e=65537)    
plain_text_original="xyz"    
cipher_text=new_key.encrypt(plain_text_original.encode("utf-8"),123455)[0]    
print(cipher_text)     
print(cipher_text.decode("utf-8"))
```

The cipher_text is as below:

```
b"\x8cwO\xf5\xc9\xd3\xa4c|8\xcb\xfc\xef\xbd\xca\xb1&\x15aj\xec\xff\xd9\xeL"
try decode("utf-8")
```

it shows exception UnicodeDecodeError

Why is this?

Comment: What version of python are you using? 2.x and 3.x handle strings dramatically different. Well I guess you are using 3.x because of the bute type, sorry.

Comment: Why do you think the ciphertext is valid UTF8, or valid text at all? It isn´t.

Answer (score 0):

Ciphertext, despite the name, does not consist of printable text. All *modern ciphers* - like other cryptographic primitives - operate on bits for their input output.

This means that to use text for input you need to perform [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding) such as UTF-8, ASCII, ISO-Latin etc. The output is also in bits, so if you require text you many need to [encode](/questions/tagged/encode) the binary to text. Common encoders are hexadecimals (easier for human consumption) and base64 (more efficient) encoding.

A good encryption method delivers output that is indistinguishable from random. As not all bytes can be decoded to readable text it is impossible to perform character decoding directly on the output of a cipher.

Of course you might get "lucky" and *not* get a decoding error or exception. In the worst case you may lose data as many decoders silently skip or replace bytes that cannot be decoded.